# "ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast" error while creating simple RMI application

Tags: java, rmi

I am creating my first, very simple RMI client-server application.

Here is the code:

Interface "ICommunication"

```
package itu.exercies.RMI.server;

    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ICommunication extends Remote  
{
    public String doCommunicate(String name) throws RemoteException; 

}
```

Interface implementation "CommunicationImpl":

```
package itu.exercies.RMI.server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class CommunicationImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ICommunication {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CommunicationImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public String doCommunicate(String name) throws RemoteException {

        return "Hello this is server , whats up " +name+ " ?!\n";
    }

}
```

Here is my main class of the server "CommunicationServer":

```
package itu.exercies.RMI.server;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;


public class CommunicationServer {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws RemoteException 
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        CommunicationImpl imp = new CommunicationImpl();
        Naming.rebind("CommunicationImpl", imp);
        System.out.println("Server started...");
        System.out.println("Object successfully registered. It is bound to the name 'CommunicationImpl'.");

    }

}
```

And this is my client "CommunicationClient":

```
package itu.exercies.RMI.client;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import itu.exercies.RMI.server.CommunicationImpl;

public class CommunicationClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {

        String url = new String("rmi://localhost/CommunicationImpl");
        CommunicationImpl comm = (CommunicationImpl)Naming.lookup(url);
        String reply = comm.doCommunicate("Wiktor");
        System.out.println(reply);


    }

}
```

Now when I try to run it:

1. I navigate to bin directory of my project using Terminal
2. I run rmiregistry from there
3. I run my CommunicationServer from new Terminal window (and it prints out the messages so it seems to work)
4. I open third terminal window and when i try to run my CommunicationClient it throws an exception.

> java itu.exercies.RMI.client.CommunicationClientException in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot be cast to itu.exercies.RMI.server.CommunicationImpl
>       at itu.exercies.RMI.client.CommunicationClient.main(CommunicationClient.java:14)

So far I have tried to fix it by creating a stub of 'CommunicationImpl' object using rmic but now instead of '$Proxy0' the error refers to 'CommunicationImpl_Stub':

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: itu.exercies.RMI.server.CommunicationImpl_Stub cannot be cast to itu.exercies.RMI.server.CommunicationImpl
>       at itu.exercies.RMI.client.CommunicationClient.main(CommunicationClient.java:14)

**At this point I have no idea were to look for errors. Can anybody give me any suggestions?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Replace

```
CommunicationImpl comm = (CommunicationImpl) Naming.lookup(url);
```

with

```
ICommunication comm = (ICommunication) Naming.lookup(url);
```

`CommunicationImpl` is the server implementation of the `ICommunication`. The client neither knows nor cares about the implementation, only the interface.

Comment: @Booyaches Exactly so. The CommunicationImpl object is remote. You don't have it locally. You have something else that implements the same remote interface. That's what the remote interface is for.

Comment: I did it.. but it still gives the same exception if Client and Server are two different applications (although interfaces are written in an exactly same wordings..)